# Persisting Data Across Shared Library Calls in Linux

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, shared-memory

**Background**

I am developing a shared library that manages an embedded Ethernet switch.  This library is called by an assortment of switch-aware management applications and is designed to be the only interface to the device.  The particular switch in question is designed for enterprise applications and expects the controlling CPU to manage much of the internal state.  To do this, I need to store a table of data that will persist across multiple calls of the library from different applications.

To this end, I have been considering shared memory with the appropriate concurrency guards. This, however raises a number of questions due to the dynamic nature of a shared library.

**Questions**

(1)  Does there always need to be a running process to retain this memory?

(2)  Since my library is constantly being loaded and unloaded, what happens when all calls exit?  Who "owns" the memory at that point or does it leak?

(3)  Is there a better system to persist an array of `struct`s across multiple calls of my library (I had considered flat files but filesystem access is quite limited).

**Additional Information**

- Individual calls to the library are atomic and independent.
- The library has no dependencies and does not `fork` any children.
- The data being tracked needs to be maintained for the entire boot time of the unit.
- The platform is a custom version of the 3.x Linux kernel.
- All code is being written in C with a focus on reusability and portability.

Comment: I think System-V shared memory is essentially like a file. It's there until you delete it. No process needs to own it at any point.

Comment: And if you need it to persist across reboots, you might want a cron job that attaches to the shared memory and serializes it to a file on some schedule, as well as a system shutdown job that does the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I managed to come up with a working solution through much trial and error.  For any who stumble onto this in the future, below is what worked for me.

**Overview**

I ended up using the System-V "SHM-style" shared memory.  As it turns out, this memory is stored with the running system until it is explicitly deleted (or the system is rebooted).  Any process my attach to it provided it presents the appropriate key when attaching.

**Answers to Questions**

(1)  No, there does not always need to be a running process to retain the memory as it is stored with the system.

(2)  As the various calls enter / exit, the shared memory segment is attached / detached repeatedly.  None of these actions causes the memory to be destroyed; it is retained with the system until explicitly deleted.  If the memory is never deleted, it will leak.

(3)  I can't answer if there is a *better* solution however System-V shared memory was pretty easy to set up and answered all of my requirements.

**Sample Code**

**Note:** this is for illustration purposes and could probably stand to be optimized.  It should mostly work however you will need to fill in some of the blanks based on your exact requirements.

```
/* Attaches to a shared memory segment.  If the segment doesn't exist, it is
 * created.  If it does exist, it is attached and returned.  Semaphores are
 * expected to be handled by the caller.  Returns 0 on success and -errno
 * on failure.
 *
 * Params:
 *   size  - Size of memory segment to create
 *   local - Pointer to attached memory region; populated by this function
 */
int16_t shm_attach(u_int32_t size, void **local)
{
    key_t key;
    int shmid;

    // Create unique-ish key
    key = ftok("/path/to/any/file", 'Z');

    // Determine if shared segment already exists
    shmid = shmget(key, size, 0666 | IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL);
    if (shmid == -1)
    {
        if (errno == EEXIST)
        {
            // Segment exists; attach to it and return
            printf("%s: SHM exists\n", __func__);
            shmid = shmget(key, size, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
            printf("%s: SHM ID = %d\n", __func__, shmid);
            *local = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
            return 0;

        } else
        {
            // Unexpected error
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: Error while initializing shared memory: %d\n", __func__, -errno);
            return -errno;
        }
    } else
    {
        // Segment didn't exist and was created; initialize and return it
        printf("%s: SHM created\n", __func__);
        printf("%s: SHM ID = %d\n", __func__, shmid);
        *local = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);

        // Initialize shared memory with whatever contents you need here
        memset(*local, 0x00, size);
        // ...

        return 0;
    }
}

/* Detaches from a shared memory segment.  Semaphores are expected to be
 * handled by caller.  Returns 0 on success and -errno on failure.
 *
 * Params:
 *   addr  - Local address of shared memory segment
 */
int16_t shm_detach(void *addr)
{
    if (shmdt(addr) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Error detaching shared memory: %d\n", __func__, -errno);
        return -errno;
    }

    return 0;
}

// Fill this in with your actual data types
typedef struct {
    int foo;
} your_shm_storage_t;

// Sample main with basic usage.  Not that this will never delete the SHM
// block so the memory will technically leak until the next reboot.  This
// is a sample, not the entire application.  =P
int main()
{
     sem_t *sem;
     your_shm_storage_t *shared;

    // Open shared memory
    sem = sem_open("/your_sem_name", O_CREAT, 0666, 1);
    sem_wait(sem);
    shm_attach(sizeof(your_shm_storage_t), (void **)&shared);

    // Do stuff with shared memory
    shared->foo++;
    printf("foo = %d\n", shared->foo);

    shm_detach(shared);
    sem_post(sem);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```